# Can I store a variable for each patch or should I use turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I am modeling tax evasion. My initial thought was to led a random number of patches be "businesses" and have wandering turtles that chose to shop at the business that can offer the best price within a given range of the turtle.

I need to somehow store the total transactions (turnover) of each business (random patches).

In addition, each business will either chose to report all income to the tax authority, or choose to evade a certain amount, which in turn will depend on each business' profile - some are willing to evade if the competition is to high, some always evade, and some never evade.

So my question is; can I assign each business-patch a different "personality", store the sum of transactions, and make them report their income? Or can these kinds of variables only be stored in a turtle? In other words, should I make a model with several breeds of turtles in stead, where some are customers and some are stationary businesses?

Answer (score 2):

Patches can have `patches-own` variables just like turtles can have `turtles-own` variables. See: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#variables

If your businesses really are stationary, it makes sense to model them as patches.

Modeling them as turtles does give you a bit more flexibility, however. You could `set shape "house"` for visual effect. You could have them enter in a network eventually. You could change their size according to some relevant variable. Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That really helps. Eventually, I want to model a social network as well. Am I correct in assuming I have to model them as turtles to create a network structure?